# For () for the vars

Tags: javascript

Sorry if the title is misleading, had no idea on how to title it.

Here's a var :

```
         var rects = [
             {x: 32, y: 32, w: 32, h: 32},
             {x: 32, y: 32, w: 32, h: 32},
             {x: 0, y: 0, w: 32, h: 32}

         ], i = 0, r;
```

Now, I want to do something like this :

```
 for (nb = 0; nb > 10; nb++;) {
         var rects = [ {x: 32 * nb, y: 32 * nb, w: 32, h: 32} ], i = 0, r;
 }
```

(Of course this doesn't work).

How can I do this ? Thanks !

Comment: Can you describe what the goal is?

Comment: Do you want to dynamically create an array instead of writing out every value in `rects`?

Comment: I bet you want `var rects = []; for (....) { rects.push(...); }`;

Comment: Nicholas : It's some rectangles for a canvas. x and y are the pos.

Comment: You are redefining the array each time, not appending to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `Array.from` :

```
let rects = Array.from({length:3} , _=>({x: 32, y: 32, w: 32, h: 32})), i = 0, r;
```

Or use a traditional for loop:

```
let rects = [], i = 0, r;

for(let index = 0; index < 3; index++)
  rects[index] = {x: 32, y: 32, w: 32, h: 32};
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I just wanted the x and y to be multiplicated by "index", but that's the right code.